# How to pattern match a tuple

Tags: elixir

I've been trying to pattern match a tuple I have so I can pass some data to another function but I'm failing to do so.
It looks like that:
I want to get the Album data.

```
  {[
    "name": [
      %{
        __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "albums">,
        __struct__: MyApp.Repo.Schemas.Album,
        key: value
      },
      %{
        __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "albums">,
        __struct__: MyApp.Repo.Schemas.Album,
        key: value
      }
    ]
  ], [:"name2"]}
```

I was trying to do it like that:

```
    case GenServer.multi_call(Node.list(), :service, :get_albums, 10000) do
      {[_node, [{albums}] | _rest]} ->
 ##rest of the code
```

Few other attempts...

```
  [{_node, [albums]} | _], [_rest]
  
  
  {[_node, [albums]], | _}
```

How can I achieve that? I want to access albums so I can pass them to the next function where I insert them to my DB. I've been reading how to pattern match and with simpler cases I don't have issues but this time I cannot get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When matching a tuple, the tuple size must match. Here you are trying to match a size 2 tuple (`{[name: ...], [:name2]}`) with a size 1 tuple pattern.

Then, the first element is a keyword list, which typically doesn't work too well with pattern-matching, it might be better to use the [`Keyword`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Keyword.html) module. If you are sure that the key `:name` is going to be first, you can however go with something like:

```elixir
{[{:name, albums} | _rest], _list}
```